# Can you fill in the gaps in this number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

The number sequence is

```
73, 70, 49, 52, 35, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 72,.....
```

Can you fill in the gaps and predict what happens after 72?

I have updated the hints below.

*Hint 1*

> What are the factors of each number? Calculate factors for each number!

*Hint 2*

> This is a mathematical problem, but does not require complicated maths

*Hint 3*

> If a sequence using exactly the same mathematical rules is started with a different number a different pattern develops.  For example; [ 1, 1, 1, 1, ........ ] and [ 48, 48, 48, 48, ........]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 5 missing values are:

> 24, 12, 3, 9, 81

After 72:

> Each subsequent value will be 9 less until it gets to 9, then start over at 81, repeating forever.

The method:

> To calculate the next value, add the digits of the current value and multiply by the first digit of the current value.

Comment: Great Job - Well done :-)

Answer (score 1):

The gaps:

> 34, 21, 16, 7, 0

Reasoning:

> Every other number is in octal. When converted to decimal, the values would be:
>  73, 56, 49, 42, 35, 28, 21, 14, 7, 0
>  Which (after 73) is of course multiples of 7 descending

What comes after 72 (less sure about this part):

> I think the 73, 72, is another countdown. The first number in each sub-sequence is the largest multiple of 7 less than octal 73 or octal 72, etc.

So the sequence will continue...

> 73, 70, 49, 52, 35, 34, 21, 16, 7, 0
>  72, 70, 49, 52, 35, 34, 21, 16, 7, 0
>  71, 70, 49, 52, 35, 34, 21, 16, 7, 0
>  70, 61, 42, 43, 28, 25, 14, 7, 0
>  (Sub-sequence has shifted left and octal/decimal values are flipped)

Comment: Nice reasoning and ideas, but very sorry this is not correct....

Comment: ...you *are* correct to be working along mathematical lines, but I am afraid that this particular approach is not correct

Comment: The idea of every other number in octal giving the sequence is brilliant, but sadly not correct.... --- so +1 for a great idea, but sorry not the correct approach

Comment: @tom haha, thank you :) no need to apologize